# How can I get Eclipse (or any IDE) to index .td files?

Tags: eclipse, ide, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm working on an LLVM compiler backend, which involves editing a lot of .td files (written for TableGen). The functions defined in these also get used in various .cpp files, but my IDE becomes extremely cluttered because everything looks undefined to it.

Comment: You will need a plugin to do the parsing.
This could work, but I have never tested it: https://github.com/serge1/Eclipse-TableGen

Answer (score 1):

LLVM provides syntax highlighters for `.td` files for few editor like vim, emacs etc.
You can find them in `llvm/utils` directory.

vim syntax highlighter for `.td` files is at `llvm/utils/vim/syntax/tablegen.vim`.